# C# Regex second character to last character Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, regex

I need to change between second character and last character in my string.

ex..

Apple => A****

Sky => S**

Black => B****

Can i do it, use by C# Regex class ?

Best Regard,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I don't think you need regex for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need RegEx for that.

Since you don't care what the chars are and want to replace all of them with 1 character, you can do it like this:

Thinking of it, you don't need to replace the chars...

```
private static string ReplaceTailWithStars(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return "";

    return s.First() + new string('*', s.Length - 1);
}
```

However, as it has been mentioned in the comments, you should be more specific with your question and provide examples for what you have tried so far to show your own effort.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i know other way. but i want more solid code. your answer help for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RegEx. first you should have a pattern , see below link to create a regex pattern:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

then in your code,

**boolean result= new Regex(sampleString).IsMatch(samplePattern);**

if result is true means your sample string is math with your pattern.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i want to replace to specification character from source string. your answer help for me.